# How to read mails of particular mail id

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to read mails of particular mail id.

**ex:-** i want to read mails coming from  **xyz@gmail.com** in my inbox, and show only those mails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well post the code or some infomation of *your* inbox design and we can give you a way to filter emails.

Comment: In my own contact apps there is an E-mail button for each contacts, so if i press that button it has to work like showing all mails of that corresponding person from my inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

1. Implement your own email client to fetch emails.
2. Fetch emails from particular email id.
3. Search for email coming from `xyz@gmail.com`.
4. Show the searched mail.

Comment: Thanks Vineet for ur response, i will try this.